# How to use Load and Unload events in a user web control?

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I swear to god I tried googling it.
I have a webcontrol that logs into the database the time and date of a page load, and same of page unload.

I can't set it up to save my life.

can somebody provide a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UserControl's Load and Unload events.

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Log to Database
    }

    protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Log to Database
    }
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is ASP.Net Page Life Cycle

[image]

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. I added a response.write command on page load, and it does nothing. the event is not called... :\ you have any idea why that is?

Comment: Make sure **AutoEventWireup="true"** is true for Control, and event is as **protected** (not private). `<%@ Control AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>`. Then set a break point at `{`. If still doesn't work, upload the control's code behind file.

Answer (score 0):

The page fires the load event, which recursively goes through all of its controls, including your user control, to fire that load event on it.  same action occurs for Unload.  The page controls it all, which is controlled by the module that controls the ASP.NET framework.